# Better way of writing a long and simple if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am writing some custom values for a variable. 
Is there a better way of writing this?

```
if val == 1:
    val = -20
elif val == 2:
    val = -15
elif val == 3:
    val = -10
elif val == 4:
    val = -5
elif val == 5:
    val = 0
elif val == 6:
    val = 4
elif val == 7:
    val = 8
elif val == 8:
    val = 12
elif val == 9:
    val = 16
elif val == 10:
    val = 20
```

Comment: Use a dictionary to look up the new values by the old ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to find the pattern and use some math. You're incrementing with 5 until `val` is 5 and then increment with 4 from there.

```
if 1 <= val < 5:
    val = -25 + 5 * val 
elif 5 <= val <= 10:
    val = (val - 5) * 4
```

Or if you cannot find the pattern, you could use a dictionary instead (as suggested in the comments).

```
values = {1: -20, 2: -15, 3: -5, ... , 10: 20}  # Don't write '...', fill with your values.
val = values[val]
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Michael Butscher for the idea:

```
    values = {
        1: -20,
        2: -15,
        3: -10,
        4: -5,
        5: 0,
        6: 4,
        7: 8,
        8: 12,
        9: 16,
        10: 20,
    }

    value = values.get(value)
```

Comment: You don't need strings. A dictionary works with integers as keys as well.

Comment: Also remember that `values.get(value)` will return `None` if it cannot find the key. You could use `values[value]` if you want it to throw an error if it doesn't exist, or use `values.get(value, default_value)` to return the `default_value` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks Ted, the value in this case is certain.

Answer (score 0):

If your

> val

is a random value then you can use a dictionary like below

```
options = {1: -20, 2:-15,3:-10,4 : -5, 5:0,6 : 4,7 : 8, 8 : 12, 9 : 16 , 10 : 20}
val = options[val]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've got the correct pattern, the most general solution is:

```
def func(val):
    return abs(5-val)*min(max(val, -5, key=abs), 4)
```

Output:

```
[func(i) for i in range(-5, 13)]
[..., -50, -45, -40, -35, -30, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write a loop, and increment by `5` if less than 5, and `4` if greater than 5. Then add the values to a dictionary.

```
counter = -20

result = {}
for number in range(1, 11):
    result[number] = counter

    if number < 5:
        counter += 5
    else:
        counter += 4

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: -20, 2: -15, 3: -10, 4: -5, 5: 0, 6: 4, 7: 8, 8: 12, 9: 16, 10: 20}
```

Then if you want to get the values from the dictionary, you can do `result[key]` as shown in the other answers.